# Validate a JavaScript function name

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, function

What would be a regular expression which I can use to match a valid JavaScript function name...

E.g. `myfunction` would be valid but `my<\fun\>ction` would be invalid.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_])?
```

Comment: I am using ajax call in my app and at the end of the url string (used to ajax) I append a callback function name (which would be executed after the ajax call returns)... and on the server side I need to validate that what callback function is a valid javascript function name... so that if i have ..param=value1&param2=value2&callback=myfunction, my server code in java would validate 'myfunction' for special characters and would invalidate if myfunction is something liike 'my&8<scri>>function'

Comment: Doesn't that imply Eval! Oooh, ick, nasty!

Comment: Are you open to solutions that don't involve regular expressions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**[EDIT]** See [@bobince's post below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2008444/244128) for a more correct and thorough answer.  This answer has been retained for reference and edited to be less wrong.

A valid name in JavaScript must start with a Unicode letter (`\p{L}`), dollar sign, or underscore then can contain any of those characters as well as numbers, combining diacritical (accent) characters, and various joiner punctuation and zero-width spaces.  Additionally, it cannot be a word reserved by the JavaScript language (e.g. `abstract`, `as`, `boolean`, `break`, `byte`, `case`, etc).

A full regular expression solution would be quite complicated in plain JavaScript but the [XRegExp Unicode plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode) could greatly simplify the task.  [This online function name tester](http://mothereff.in/js-variables) might also be useful.

**[ORIGINAL]** Here is an *incomplete* regular expression, using *only the US ASCII letters*:

```javascript
var fnNameRegex = /^[$A-Z_][0-9A-Z_$]*$/i;
```

You also must check that it doesn't match any reserved words (e.g. abstract, boolean, break, byte, ..., while, with, etc).  Here's [a start for that list](http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm), and an example function:

```javascript
var isValidFunctionName = function() {
  var validName = /^[$A-Z_][0-9A-Z_$]*$/i;
  var reserved = {
    'abstract':true,
    'boolean':true,
    // ...
    'with':true
  };
  return function(s) {
    // Ensure a valid name and not reserved.
    return validName.test(s) && !reserved[s];
  };
}();
```

Comment: According to http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf a name can also start with a '$', a '_' and also a unicode escape sequence, though I'm not sure why one would want that in a name.

Comment: wow... I did not think about reserved words.. I wonder how my app would behave if I use reserved words in callback function names..but thanks.. ./^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*$/ should be good for start

Comment: Thanks for the link! I didn't realize that "$" and "_" are valid starters, but I should have known from using libraries like Prototype and jQuery...

Comment: The `$` character is valid anywhere in a name, not only the beginning.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, just plain incorrect. [The standard](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6) allows far more than just English letters and digits. The first character can be *any* Unicode letter (not just `A-Za-z`!), `$`, `_`, or a unicode escape sequence. The rest can be any of those or any Unicode digit, combining mark, connector punctuation, and even format-control characters. This answer is very English-centric, even Europeans are left out!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: yes, agreed.  I posted this answer before becoming familiar with the ECMA-262 spec.  Ideally I could "un-accept" my own answer in favor of @bobince's; I'd prefer not to delete mine so that the straw-man implementation is still there for others to see but perhaps deleting it is the best option.  Ideas?

Comment: @maerics: For what (little) it matters, I think you've pitched things *exactly* right by leaving the answer but adding the edit you added. Nice one.

Answer (score 51):

This is more complicated than you might think. According to the [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/ecma-262.htm) standard, an identifier is:

```
an IdentifierName that is not a ReservedWord
```

so first you would have to check that the identifier is not one of:

```
instanceof typeof break do new var case else return void catch finally
continue for switch while this with debugger function throw default if
try delete in
```

and potentially some others in the future.

An IdentifierName starts with:

```
a letter
the $ sign
the _ underscore
```

and can further comprise any of those characters plus:

```
a number
a combining diacritical (accent) character
various joiner punctuation and zero-width spaces
```

These characters are defined in terms of Unicode character classes, so `[A-Z]` is incomplete. `Ä` is a letter; `ξ` is a letter; `京` is a letter. You can use all of those in identifiers including those used for function names.

Unfortunately, JavaScript RegExp is not Unicode-aware. If you say `\w` you only get the ASCII alphanumerics. There is no feasible way to check the validity of non-ASCII identifier characters short of carrying around the relevant parts of the Unicode Character Database with your script, which would be very large and clumsy.

You could try simply allowing all non-ASCII characters, for example:

```
^[_$a-zA-Z\xA0-\uFFFF][_$a-zA-Z0-9\xA0-\uFFFF]*$
```

Comment: To give you an idea of how large and clumsy it would be to create such a regular expression, [I’ve posted a 11,335-character version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9392578/96656) that reliably validates JavaScript identifiers based on ECMAScript 5.1 and Unicode 6.1.0.

Answer (score 43):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2008353) is incorrect. [bobince’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2008444) is more like it.

To quote [***Valid JavaScript variable names***](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers), my write-up summarizing the relevant spec sections:

> An identifier must start with `$`, `_`, or any character in the Unicode categories [“Uppercase letter (Lu)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/uppercase-letter), [“Lowercase letter (Ll)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/lowercase-letter), [“Titlecase letter (Lt)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/titlecase-letter), [“Modifier letter (Lm)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/modifier-letter), [“Other letter (Lo)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/other-letter), or [“Letter number (Nl)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/letter-number).
>
> The rest of the string can contain the same characters, plus any *U+200C zero width non-joiner* characters, *U+200D zero width joiner* characters, and characters in the Unicode categories [“Non-spacing mark (Mn)”](http://graphemica.com/unicode/categories/nonspacing-mark), [“Spacing combining mark (Mc)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/spacing-combining-mark), [“Decimal digit number (Nd)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/decimal-digit-number), or [“Connector punctuation (Pc)”](http://graphemica.com/categories/connector-punctuation).

The linked article covers some more gotchas, but that’s the gist of it.

I’ve also created [a tool](http://mothereff.in/js-variables) that will tell you if any string that you enter is a valid JavaScript variable name according to ECMAScript 5.1 and Unicode 6.1:

[image: JavaScript variable name validator]

---

P.S. To give you an idea of how wrong the currently accepted answer is: if you were to summarize all these rules in a single ASCII-only regular expression for JavaScript, **it would be 11,236 characters long** (for ECMAScript 5.1 / Unicode 6.1.0). Here it is:

```
// ES5.1 / Unicode 6.1
/^(?!(?:do|if|in|for|let|new|try|var|case|else|enum|eval|false|null|this|true|void|with|break|catch|class|const|super|throw|while|yield|delete|export|import|public|return|static|switch|typeof|default|extends|finally|package|private|continue|debugger|function|arguments|interface|protected|implements|instanceof)$)[$A-Z\_a-z\xaa\xb5\xba\xc0-\xd6\xd8-\xf6\xf8-\u02c1\u02c6-\u02d1\u02e0-\u02e4\u02ec\u02ee\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037a-\u037d\u0386\u0388-\u038a\u038c\u038e-\u03a1\u03a3-\u03f5\u03f7-\u0481\u048a-\u0527\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05d0-\u05ea\u05f0-\u05f2\u0620-\u064a\u066e\u066f\u0671-\u06d3\u06d5\u06e5\u06e6\u06ee\u06ef\u06fa-\u06fc\u06ff\u0710\u0712-\u072f\u074d-\u07a5\u07b1\u07ca-\u07ea\u07f4\u07f5\u07fa\u0800-\u0815\u081a\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08a0\u08a2-\u08ac\u0904-\u0939\u093d\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0977\u0979-\u097f\u0985-\u098c\u098f\u0990\u0993-\u09a8\u09aa-\u09b0\u09b2\u09b6-\u09b9\u09bd\u09ce\u09dc\u09dd\u09df-\u09e1\u09f0\u09f1\u0a05-\u0a0a\u0a0f\u0a10\u0a13-\u0a28\u0a2a-\u0a30\u0a32\u0a33\u0a35\u0a36\u0a38\u0a39\u0a59-\u0a5c\u0a5e\u0a72-\u0a74\u0a85-\u0a8d\u0a8f-\u0a91\u0a93-\u0aa8\u0aaa-\u0ab0\u0ab2\u0ab3\u0ab5-\u0ab9\u0abd\u0ad0\u0ae0\u0ae1\u0b05-\u0b0c\u0b0f\u0b10\u0b13-\u0b28\u0b2a-\u0b30\u0b32\u0b33\u0b35-\u0b39\u0b3d\u0b5c\u0b5d\u0b5f-\u0b61\u0b71\u0b83\u0b85-\u0b8a\u0b8e-\u0b90\u0b92-\u0b95\u0b99\u0b9a\u0b9c\u0b9e\u0b9f\u0ba3\u0ba4\u0ba8-\u0baa\u0bae-\u0bb9\u0bd0\u0c05-\u0c0c\u0c0e-\u0c10\u0c12-\u0c28\u0c2a-\u0c33\u0c35-\u0c39\u0c3d\u0c58\u0c59\u0c60\u0c61\u0c85-\u0c8c\u0c8e-\u0c90\u0c92-\u0ca8\u0caa-\u0cb3\u0cb5-\u0cb9\u0cbd\u0cde\u0ce0\u0ce1\u0cf1\u0cf2\u0d05-\u0d0c\u0d0e-\u0d10\u0d12-\u0d3a\u0d3d\u0d4e\u0d60\u0d61\u0d7a-\u0d7f\u0d85-\u0d96\u0d9a-\u0db1\u0db3-\u0dbb\u0dbd\u0dc0-\u0dc6\u0e01-\u0e30\u0e32\u0e33\u0e40-\u0e46\u0e81\u0e82\u0e84\u0e87\u0e88\u0e8a\u0e8d\u0e94-\u0e97\u0e99-\u0e9f\u0ea1-\u0ea3\u0ea5\u0ea7\u0eaa\u0eab\u0ead-\u0eb0\u0eb2\u0eb3\u0ebd\u0ec0-\u0ec4\u0ec6\u0edc-\u0edf\u0f00\u0f40-\u0f47\u0f49-\u0f6c\u0f88-\u0f8c\u1000-\u102a\u103f\u1050-\u1055\u105a-\u105d\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106e-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108e\u10a0-\u10c5\u10c7\u10cd\u10d0-\u10fa\u10fc-\u1248\u124a-\u124d\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125a-\u125d\u1260-\u1288\u128a-\u128d\u1290-\u12b0\u12b2-\u12b5\u12b8-\u12be\u12c0\u12c2-\u12c5\u12c8-\u12d6\u12d8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135a\u1380-\u138f\u13a0-\u13f4\u1401-\u166c\u166f-\u167f\u1681-\u169a\u16a0-\u16ea\u16ee-\u16f0\u1700-\u170c\u170e-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176c\u176e-\u1770\u1780-\u17b3\u17d7\u17dc\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18a8\u18aa\u18b0-\u18f5\u1900-\u191c\u1950-\u196d\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19ab\u19c1-\u19c7\u1a00-\u1a16\u1a20-\u1a54\u1aa7\u1b05-\u1b33\u1b45-\u1b4b\u1b83-\u1ba0\u1bae\u1baf\u1bba-\u1be5\u1c00-\u1c23\u1c4d-\u1c4f\u1c5a-\u1c7d\u1ce9-\u1cec\u1cee-\u1cf1\u1cf5\u1cf6\u1d00-\u1dbf\u1e00-\u1f15\u1f18-\u1f1d\u1f20-\u1f45\u1f48-\u1f4d\u1f50-\u1f57\u1f59\u1f5b\u1f5d\u1f5f-\u1f7d\u1f80-\u1fb4\u1fb6-\u1fbc\u1fbe\u1fc2-\u1fc4\u1fc6-\u1fcc\u1fd0-\u1fd3\u1fd6-\u1fdb\u1fe0-\u1fec\u1ff2-\u1ff4\u1ff6-\u1ffc\u2071\u207f\u2090-\u209c\u2102\u2107\u210a-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211d\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212a-\u212d\u212f-\u2139\u213c-\u213f\u2145-\u2149\u214e\u2160-\u2188\u2c00-\u2c2e\u2c30-\u2c5e\u2c60-\u2ce4\u2ceb-\u2cee\u2cf2\u2cf3\u2d00-\u2d25\u2d27\u2d2d\u2d30-\u2d67\u2d6f\u2d80-\u2d96\u2da0-\u2da6\u2da8-\u2dae\u2db0-\u2db6\u2db8-\u2dbe\u2dc0-\u2dc6\u2dc8-\u2dce\u2dd0-\u2dd6\u2dd8-\u2dde\u2e2f\u3005-\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3031-\u3035\u3038-\u303c\u3041-\u3096\u309d-\u309f\u30a1-\u30fa\u30fc-\u30ff\u3105-\u312d\u3131-\u318e\u31a0-\u31ba\u31f0-\u31ff\u3400-\u4db5\u4e00-\u9fcc\ua000-\ua48c\ua4d0-\ua4fd\ua500-\ua60c\ua610-\ua61f\ua62a\ua62b\ua640-\ua66e\ua67f-\ua697\ua6a0-\ua6ef\ua717-\ua71f\ua722-\ua788\ua78b-\ua78e\ua790-\ua793\ua7a0-\ua7aa\ua7f8-\ua801\ua803-\ua805\ua807-\ua80a\ua80c-\ua822\ua840-\ua873\ua882-\ua8b3\ua8f2-\ua8f7\ua8fb\ua90a-\ua925\ua930-\ua946\ua960-\ua97c\ua984-\ua9b2\ua9cf\uaa00-\uaa28\uaa40-\uaa42\uaa44-\uaa4b\uaa60-\uaa76\uaa7a\uaa80-\uaaaf\uaab1\uaab5\uaab6\uaab9-\uaabd\uaac0\uaac2\uaadb-\uaadd\uaae0-\uaaea\uaaf2-\uaaf4\uab01-\uab06\uab09-\uab0e\uab11-\uab16\uab20-\uab26\uab28-\uab2e\uabc0-\uabe2\uac00-\ud7a3\ud7b0-\ud7c6\ud7cb-\ud7fb\uf900-\ufa6d\ufa70-\ufad9\ufb00-\ufb06\ufb13-\ufb17\ufb1d\ufb1f-\ufb28\ufb2a-\ufb36\ufb38-\ufb3c\ufb3e\ufb40\ufb41\ufb43\ufb44\ufb46-\ufbb1\ufbd3-\ufd3d\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufdf0-\ufdfb\ufe70-\ufe74\ufe76-\ufefc\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a\uff66-\uffbe\uffc2-\uffc7\uffca-\uffcf\uffd2-\uffd7\uffda-\uffdc][$A-Z\_a-z\xaa\xb5\xba\xc0-\xd6\xd8-\xf6\xf8-\u02c1\u02c6-\u02d1\u02e0-\u02e4\u02ec\u02ee\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037a-\u037d\u0386\u0388-\u038a\u038c\u038e-\u03a1\u03a3-\u03f5\u03f7-\u0481\u048a-\u0527\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05d0-\u05ea\u05f0-\u05f2\u0620-\u064a\u066e\u066f\u0671-\u06d3\u06d5\u06e5\u06e6\u06ee\u06ef\u06fa-\u06fc\u06ff\u0710\u0712-\u072f\u074d-\u07a5\u07b1\u07ca-\u07ea\u07f4\u07f5\u07fa\u0800-\u0815\u081a\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08a0\u08a2-\u08ac\u0904-\u0939\u093d\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0977\u0979-\u097f\u0985-\u098c\u098f\u0990\u0993-\u09a8\u09aa-\u09b0\u09b2\u09b6-\u09b9\u09bd\u09ce\u09dc\u09dd\u09df-\u09e1\u09f0\u09f1\u0a05-\u0a0a\u0a0f\u0a10\u0a13-\u0a28\u0a2a-\u0a30\u0a32\u0a33\u0a35\u0a36\u0a38\u0a39\u0a59-\u0a5c\u0a5e\u0a72-\u0a74\u0a85-\u0a8d\u0a8f-\u0a91\u0a93-\u0aa8\u0aaa-\u0ab0\u0ab2\u0ab3\u0ab5-\u0ab9\u0abd\u0ad0\u0ae0\u0ae1\u0b05-\u0b0c\u0b0f\u0b10\u0b13-\u0b28\u0b2a-\u0b30\u0b32\u0b33\u0b35-\u0b39\u0b3d\u0b5c\u0b5d\u0b5f-\u0b61\u0b71\u0b83\u0b85-\u0b8a\u0b8e-\u0b90\u0b92-\u0b95\u0b99\u0b9a\u0b9c\u0b9e\u0b9f\u0ba3\u0ba4\u0ba8-\u0baa\u0bae-\u0bb9\u0bd0\u0c05-\u0c0c\u0c0e-\u0c10\u0c12-\u0c28\u0c2a-\u0c33\u0c35-\u0c39\u0c3d\u0c58\u0c59\u0c60\u0c61\u0c85-\u0c8c\u0c8e-\u0c90\u0c92-\u0ca8\u0caa-\u0cb3\u0cb5-\u0cb9\u0cbd\u0cde\u0ce0\u0ce1\u0cf1\u0cf2\u0d05-\u0d0c\u0d0e-\u0d10\u0d12-\u0d3a\u0d3d\u0d4e\u0d60\u0d61\u0d7a-\u0d7f\u0d85-\u0d96\u0d9a-\u0db1\u0db3-\u0dbb\u0dbd\u0dc0-\u0dc6\u0e01-\u0e30\u0e32\u0e33\u0e40-\u0e46\u0e81\u0e82\u0e84\u0e87\u0e88\u0e8a\u0e8d\u0e94-\u0e97\u0e99-\u0e9f\u0ea1-\u0ea3\u0ea5\u0ea7\u0eaa\u0eab\u0ead-\u0eb0\u0eb2\u0eb3\u0ebd\u0ec0-\u0ec4\u0ec6\u0edc-\u0edf\u0f00\u0f40-\u0f47\u0f49-\u0f6c\u0f88-\u0f8c\u1000-\u102a\u103f\u1050-\u1055\u105a-\u105d\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106e-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108e\u10a0-\u10c5\u10c7\u10cd\u10d0-\u10fa\u10fc-\u1248\u124a-\u124d\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125a-\u125d\u1260-\u1288\u128a-\u128d\u1290-\u12b0\u12b2-\u12b5\u12b8-\u12be\u12c0\u12c2-\u12c5\u12c8-\u12d6\u12d8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135a\u1380-\u138f\u13a0-\u13f4\u1401-\u166c\u166f-\u167f\u1681-\u169a\u16a0-\u16ea\u16ee-\u16f0\u1700-\u170c\u170e-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176c\u176e-\u1770\u1780-\u17b3\u17d7\u17dc\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18a8\u18aa\u18b0-\u18f5\u1900-\u191c\u1950-\u196d\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19ab\u19c1-\u19c7\u1a00-\u1a16\u1a20-\u1a54\u1aa7\u1b05-\u1b33\u1b45-\u1b4b\u1b83-\u1ba0\u1bae\u1baf\u1bba-\u1be5\u1c00-\u1c23\u1c4d-\u1c4f\u1c5a-\u1c7d\u1ce9-\u1cec\u1cee-\u1cf1\u1cf5\u1cf6\u1d00-\u1dbf\u1e00-\u1f15\u1f18-\u1f1d\u1f20-\u1f45\u1f48-\u1f4d\u1f50-\u1f57\u1f59\u1f5b\u1f5d\u1f5f-\u1f7d\u1f80-\u1fb4\u1fb6-\u1fbc\u1fbe\u1fc2-\u1fc4\u1fc6-\u1fcc\u1fd0-\u1fd3\u1fd6-\u1fdb\u1fe0-\u1fec\u1ff2-\u1ff4\u1ff6-\u1ffc\u2071\u207f\u2090-\u209c\u2102\u2107\u210a-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211d\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212a-\u212d\u212f-\u2139\u213c-\u213f\u2145-\u2149\u214e\u2160-\u2188\u2c00-\u2c2e\u2c30-\u2c5e\u2c60-\u2ce4\u2ceb-\u2cee\u2cf2\u2cf3\u2d00-\u2d25\u2d27\u2d2d\u2d30-\u2d67\u2d6f\u2d80-\u2d96\u2da0-\u2da6\u2da8-\u2dae\u2db0-\u2db6\u2db8-\u2dbe\u2dc0-\u2dc6\u2dc8-\u2dce\u2dd0-\u2dd6\u2dd8-\u2dde\u2e2f\u3005-\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3031-\u3035\u3038-\u303c\u3041-\u3096\u309d-\u309f\u30a1-\u30fa\u30fc-\u30ff\u3105-\u312d\u3131-\u318e\u31a0-\u31ba\u31f0-\u31ff\u3400-\u4db5\u4e00-\u9fcc\ua000-\ua48c\ua4d0-\ua4fd\ua500-\ua60c\ua610-\ua61f\ua62a\ua62b\ua640-\ua66e\ua67f-\ua697\ua6a0-\ua6ef\ua717-\ua71f\ua722-\ua788\ua78b-\ua78e\ua790-\ua793\ua7a0-\ua7aa\ua7f8-\ua801\ua803-\ua805\ua807-\ua80a\ua80c-\ua822\ua840-\ua873\ua882-\ua8b3\ua8f2-\ua8f7\ua8fb\ua90a-\ua925\ua930-\ua946\ua960-\ua97c\ua984-\ua9b2\ua9cf\uaa00-\uaa28\uaa40-\uaa42\uaa44-\uaa4b\uaa60-\uaa76\uaa7a\uaa80-\uaaaf\uaab1\uaab5\uaab6\uaab9-\uaabd\uaac0\uaac2\uaadb-\uaadd\uaae0-\uaaea\uaaf2-\uaaf4\uab01-\uab06\uab09-\uab0e\uab11-\uab16\uab20-\uab26\uab28-\uab2e\uabc0-\uabe2\uac00-\ud7a3\ud7b0-\ud7c6\ud7cb-\ud7fb\uf900-\ufa6d\ufa70-\ufad9\ufb00-\ufb06\ufb13-\ufb17\ufb1d\ufb1f-\ufb28\ufb2a-\ufb36\ufb38-\ufb3c\ufb3e\ufb40\ufb41\ufb43\ufb44\ufb46-\ufbb1\ufbd3-\ufd3d\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufdf0-\ufdfb\ufe70-\ufe74\ufe76-\ufefc\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a\uff66-\uffbe\uffc2-\uffc7\uffca-\uffcf\uffd2-\uffd7\uffda-\uffdc0-9\u0300-\u036f\u0483-\u0487\u0591-\u05bd\u05bf\u05c1\u05c2\u05c4\u05c5\u05c7\u0610-\u061a\u064b-\u0669\u0670\u06d6-\u06dc\u06df-\u06e4\u06e7\u06e8\u06ea-\u06ed\u06f0-\u06f9\u0711\u0730-\u074a\u07a6-\u07b0\u07c0-\u07c9\u07eb-\u07f3\u0816-\u0819\u081b-\u0823\u0825-\u0827\u0829-\u082d\u0859-\u085b\u08e4-\u08fe\u0900-\u0903\u093a-\u093c\u093e-\u094f\u0951-\u0957\u0962\u0963\u0966-\u096f\u0981-\u0983\u09bc\u09be-\u09c4\u09c7\u09c8\u09cb-\u09cd\u09d7\u09e2\u09e3\u09e6-\u09ef\u0a01-\u0a03\u0a3c\u0a3e-\u0a42\u0a47\u0a48\u0a4b-\u0a4d\u0a51\u0a66-\u0a71\u0a75\u0a81-\u0a83\u0abc\u0abe-\u0ac5\u0ac7-\u0ac9\u0acb-\u0acd\u0ae2\u0ae3\u0ae6-\u0aef\u0b01-\u0b03\u0b3c\u0b3e-\u0b44\u0b47\u0b48\u0b4b-\u0b4d\u0b56\u0b57\u0b62\u0b63\u0b66-\u0b6f\u0b82\u0bbe-\u0bc2\u0bc6-\u0bc8\u0bca-\u0bcd\u0bd7\u0be6-\u0bef\u0c01-\u0c03\u0c3e-\u0c44\u0c46-\u0c48\u0c4a-\u0c4d\u0c55\u0c56\u0c62\u0c63\u0c66-\u0c6f\u0c82\u0c83\u0cbc\u0cbe-\u0cc4\u0cc6-\u0cc8\u0cca-\u0ccd\u0cd5\u0cd6\u0ce2\u0ce3\u0ce6-\u0cef\u0d02\u0d03\u0d3e-\u0d44\u0d46-\u0d48\u0d4a-\u0d4d\u0d57\u0d62\u0d63\u0d66-\u0d6f\u0d82\u0d83\u0dca\u0dcf-\u0dd4\u0dd6\u0dd8-\u0ddf\u0df2\u0df3\u0e31\u0e34-\u0e3a\u0e47-\u0e4e\u0e50-\u0e59\u0eb1\u0eb4-\u0eb9\u0ebb\u0ebc\u0ec8-\u0ecd\u0ed0-\u0ed9\u0f18\u0f19\u0f20-\u0f29\u0f35\u0f37\u0f39\u0f3e\u0f3f\u0f71-\u0f84\u0f86\u0f87\u0f8d-\u0f97\u0f99-\u0fbc\u0fc6\u102b-\u103e\u1040-\u1049\u1056-\u1059\u105e-\u1060\u1062-\u1064\u1067-\u106d\u1071-\u1074\u1082-\u108d\u108f-\u109d\u135d-\u135f\u1712-\u1714\u1732-\u1734\u1752\u1753\u1772\u1773\u17b4-\u17d3\u17dd\u17e0-\u17e9\u180b-\u180d\u1810-\u1819\u18a9\u1920-\u192b\u1930-\u193b\u1946-\u194f\u19b0-\u19c0\u19c8\u19c9\u19d0-\u19d9\u1a17-\u1a1b\u1a55-\u1a5e\u1a60-\u1a7c\u1a7f-\u1a89\u1a90-\u1a99\u1b00-\u1b04\u1b34-\u1b44\u1b50-\u1b59\u1b6b-\u1b73\u1b80-\u1b82\u1ba1-\u1bad\u1bb0-\u1bb9\u1be6-\u1bf3\u1c24-\u1c37\u1c40-\u1c49\u1c50-\u1c59\u1cd0-\u1cd2\u1cd4-\u1ce8\u1ced\u1cf2-\u1cf4\u1dc0-\u1de6\u1dfc-\u1dff\u200c\u200d\u203f\u2040\u2054\u20d0-\u20dc\u20e1\u20e5-\u20f0\u2cef-\u2cf1\u2d7f\u2de0-\u2dff\u302a-\u302f\u3099\u309a\ua620-\ua629\ua66f\ua674-\ua67d\ua69f\ua6f0\ua6f1\ua802\ua806\ua80b\ua823-\ua827\ua880\ua881\ua8b4-\ua8c4\ua8d0-\ua8d9\ua8e0-\ua8f1\ua900-\ua909\ua926-\ua92d\ua947-\ua953\ua980-\ua983\ua9b3-\ua9c0\ua9d0-\ua9d9\uaa29-\uaa36\uaa43\uaa4c\uaa4d\uaa50-\uaa59\uaa7b\uaab0\uaab2-\uaab4\uaab7\uaab8\uaabe\uaabf\uaac1\uaaeb-\uaaef\uaaf5\uaaf6\uabe3-\uabea\uabec\uabed\uabf0-\uabf9\ufb1e\ufe00-\ufe0f\ufe20-\ufe26\ufe33\ufe34\ufe4d-\ufe4f\uff10-\uff19\uff3f]*$/
```

Comment: And that's why us language lawyers don't get invited to developer parties :-)

Comment: Doesn't work for unicode escape names like `\u{0061}` which can be validly inserted arbitrarily into javascript code

Comment: @JackGiffin This answer was written in 2012, when those escapes didn’t exist; it correctly specifies it matches ECMAScript 5.1 (not ES2015). Also note that `\u{61}` cannot be “arbitrarily inserted”: in regular expressions, such escapes only work [when Unicode mode is enabled through the `u` flag](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex#impact-syntax).

Comment: See [Valid JavaScript variable names in ES2015](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers-es6) for more info on how ES2015 differs from ES5 w.r.t. identifiers.

Answer (score 3):

What you wan't is close to, or perhaps, impossible -- I haven't analyzed the grammar to know for sure which.

First, take a look at the ECMAScript grammar for identifiers.  You can see one on the [ANTLR site](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1153976512034/ecmascriptA3.g).  Scroll down to where it defines identifiers:

```
identifierName:
    // snip full comment
    identifierStart (identifierPart)*
    ;

identifierStart:
    unicodeLetter
    | DOLLAR
    | UNDERSCORE
    | unicodeEscapeSequence
    ;
```

The grammar uses an EBNF, so you'll need follow those two non-terminals: `identifierStart` and `identifierPart`.  The main problem you'll run into is that you need to take into account much of unicode, and its escape characters.

For example, with `identifierStart`, we see that the regular expression will need to allow a letter, a dollar sign, an underscore, or a Unicode escape sequence as the first 'character'.

Thus, you could start your regular expression:

```
"[$_a-zA-Z]..."
```

Of course, you'll need to change `a-zA-Z` to support all of Unicode and then augment the expression to support the Unicode Escape Sequence, but hopefully that gives you a start on the process.

Of course, if you only need a rough approximation, many of the other responses provide a rough regular expression that handles a small subset of what's actually allowed.

Comment: The Unicode Escape Sequence isn't part of the identifier itself, it's just a way to write the identifier in source code.

Comment: Point taken. I assumed, perhaps incorrectly, that he might be looking at source code, or something that might be eval'd.

Comment: Yep, that's a possibility too. Meant only as a minor clarification!

Answer (score 3):

in case Regular Expression is not a must..

```
function isValidFnName( name ) {
    try {
        eval('(function() { function ' + name + '() {} })()');
    } catch( e ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

isValidFnName('myfunction');     // true
isValidFnName('my<\fun\>ction'); // false
```

Comment: This breaks when name = "t(){}function" though :)

Comment: @KevinJin Try this `eval('(function(){ setTimeout(function '+name+'(){}, 0); })');`

Comment: then empty string is valid too which shouldn't, also things like `t(){},0,function` are now valid... ;)

Comment: I think if you replace the eval line with `new Function("let "+name"=0;")` it should work no? Assuming you don't get a CORS error for (sensible) security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of Anas Nakawa's earlier answer, if the script in question is allowed to use `new Function()`, this probably covers most bases:

```
function validIdentifier(name) {
  if(typeof name !== 'string') return false;
  if(!/^([$_]|[^\0-/])+$/.test(name)) return false;
  try { new Function(`let ${name}`) } catch(e) { return false }
  return true;
}
```

Using `new Function()` ensures no code is actually evaluated, which is less unsafe (I'm not sure if I would dare to call it safe yet though, maybe someone could somehow figure out how to escape this).

The regex ensures the string is non-zero in length and avoids all control characters that might cause trouble (or spaces, someone could pass `foo; console.log("hello there")`, which would pass without the regex).

(credit to my friend Fabian Iwand for the regex, we had some fun puzzling over this alternative shorter approach)

Answer (score -1):

This should be very easy.  Valid function names can only consist of alphanumerics, parenthesis, and possibly parameter values within the parens (i don't know enough javascript to know whether parameters are defined in the function call) and must start with a letter, correct?  Therefore to validate that a string is a valid function name.  Therefore this should work:

```
[a-zA-z]+[a-zA-z0-9_]\*(\\(.*?\\))\*
```

Comment: Thanks!! my bad... I was not clear...but I am not validating paranthesis nor arguments... so just the function name... 'myfunction'
and not 'myfunction()'