# mimicing jsonp in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    var unique_code="3412313ad"// Initialize it with the unique code provided to you.
    var param1="1"; // Initialize this with the value that you wish to see.For example 1 for navbar display , 2 for the side floating pop up
                  //while 3 for a transparent overlay on the whole page.
    var domain=window.location.hostname;// current domain.
    function jsonp(url, callback) {
    var callbackName = 'jsonp_callback_' + Math.round(100000 * Math.random());
    window[callbackName] = function(data) {
    delete window[callbackName];
    document.body.removeChild(script);
    callback(data);
    };
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + 'callback=' + callbackName;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.onerror=function(){
      alert("failed to load snippet!");
    }
    }

    jsonp('http://localhost/server.php?unique_code='+unique_code+'&domain='+domain, function(data) {
      alert(data);
    if(data.status=='success'){
      alert('success');
    }else alert(data.reason);
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is a code that mimics jsonp of the jquery to get a script from the remote server.

I used the answer given in this question [JavaScript XMLHttpRequest using JsonP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780430/javascript-xmlhttprequest-using-jsonp)

Server side code would be

```
if(isset($_GET['unique_code']) && !empty($_GET['unique_code']) && isset($_GET['domain']) && !empty($_GET['domain'])){
  $unique_code=$_GET['unique_code'];
  $domain=$_GET['domain'];

  $statement=$mysqli->prepare('select * from `snippet_users` where unique_code=? AND domain=?');
  $statement->bind_param('ss',$unique_code,$domain);
  if(!$statement->execute())
     die(json_encode(array('status'=>'error','reason'=>'Server error.')));
  $result=$statement->get_result();

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
      die (json_encode(array('status'=>'success')));
  else die(json_encode(array('status'=>'error','reason'=>'Unique code/Domain error.')));
}else{
  die(json_encode(array('status'=>'error','reason'=>'Unique code/Domain error.')));
}
```

Everything is working perfectly fine but i see error in the console , somewhat like this :

[image]

What would be my solution so that i dont get this error as well as i get my  data in the alert box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputting `application/json` instead of `application/javascript`, so your browser thinks it's not valid. The json should be in a function call (callback parameter). The callback parameter should be validated on the server side however to prevent xss injection:

[Is it necessary to validate or escape the jsonp callback string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958218/is-it-necessary-to-validate-or-escape-the-jsonp-callback-string)

Comment: The callback parameter that you send in the url should be used in the output of the ajax script i.e. `jsonp_callback_123123123({status:'error',reason:'wtf'})`. Otherwise, the browser doesn't know what to do with the object.