# Can I completely stop using var?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm taking a Java course and all declarations use block scope( `int, double, boolean, etc.`).  In JavaScript however `var` is function scope.

`let` came along in ES6 and gave JS developers block scope.   I'm adjusting my coding style and am opting to get rid of `var` all together.

Is this O.K.?

Comment: Yes, even google took it out in its style guide. [Google JS Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-use-const-and-let)

Comment: Yes, if you decided to don't support older browser or if you are using a transpiler.

In ES6, there's no any reason to prefer `var` in place of `let` or `const`.

Comment: It depends on use. What benefit you will get after removing all the var?Do you have unit test case covered.Will you able to check that after replacing nothing is breaking your code

Comment: For fun, note the [difference between java and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/245073/870729)

Comment: The only useful application of `var` is that a global can be redefined in global scope multiple times without causing an error. Can happen if there are multiple scripts that define a global, but only last definition  should take effect.

Comment: @cale_b - The OP seems clear on the difference.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - indeed.  But reminded me of my favorite explanation of java vs javascript, and thought it'd be fun to share it.  Didn't mean to imply otherwise!

Comment: The problem I've been facing is that the **'let'** statement doesn't support the **"window.['my_var_name']"** feature. So, if you're dynamically getting variable values (by its string name), you will want to stick with the **'var'** statement for a while - or to update your code to use **'eval'** as you can see at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111200/windowname-equivalent-to-dynamically-access-const-and-let-declarations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use case for var in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836796/what-is-the-use-case-for-var-in-es6)

Comment: As a rule of thumb don't use ES6 in web browsers due to incompatibility issues with older browsers. Otherwise use them to your hearts content and stop using var. However var still has its uses when you need function scope.

Answer (score 9):

> Is this O.K.?

Mostly; possibly entirely. There are ***very*** few situations where you would want to use `var` instead of `let`/`const` for technical (rather than style) reasons:

- If you want to declare a global variable that becomes a property of the global object (global `let`, `const`, and `class` create globals, but they don't become properties of the global object).

  Of course, you could use `this.varName = ...` instead of `var varName`, since `this` at global scope¹ is the global object.
- If you want to have several files where any of them may be the "first" (but not last) to define the same global, as is common in older module formats, e.g.:

  ```
  var MyApp = MyApp || {};
  MyApp.something = /*...*/;
  ```

  That works because the `var MyApp` part is silently ignored if `MyApp` is already declared; the equivalent structure with `let` would fail because it cannot be used if the identifier is already declared in the current scope.

  Of course, you're probably using a new module format by now. :-) And if you aren't, again you could do

  ```
  this.MyApp = this.MyApp || {};
  MyApp.something = /*...*/;
  ```

  at global scope.¹

[There *used* to be a minor performance benefit to using `var` instead of `let` in a function where it was used as a loop counter. Recent versions of modern browsers all-but-remove that minor benefit (and it was minor anyway).]

---

¹ Note that top-level code in a module (ES2015 module, Node.js module, most bundlers...) is **not** at global scope. It's at module scope. Also note that at the top level of an ES2015 module, `this` has the value `undefined`.

Comment: `this` isn't the global in ES6 modules, might be good to clarify.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - Thanks, I've highlighted it. I did say "at global scope" and of course, module scope isn't global scope. But...

Comment: True! Definitely a distinction that some people miss though.

Comment: Why do you say that let and const create a global, the docs say they are function scoped.

Comment: `If you want to declare a global variable that becomes a property of the global object (global let, const, and class create globals, but they don't become properties of the global object)`

Comment: @johnmorsey - *"the docs say they are function scoped"* `let` and `const` aren't function-scoped, they're **block**-scoped (that is, even more narrowly-scoped than function scope). `var` is function-scoped. What I'm saying above is that `let` and `const` (and `class`) **at global scope** create globals that aren't properties of the global object. `var` at global scope creates globals that *are* properties of the global object.

Answer (score 5):

If you are only targeting platforms that support ES6, adopt let and const. Stop using var.

Comment: While less in depth, this is better answer imho. If you ever need to use `var`, you're doing it wrong. If you can use `const`, use `const`, otherwise use `let`.