# Sort array of objects by string property value without considering positive and negative value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, javascript-objects

```
Var obj = [
{band: “3”, name: “positive”},
{band: “-3”, name: “positive”}
{band: “1”, name: “positive”},
{band: “4”, name: “positive”},
{band: “-2”, name: “positive”},
{band: “2”, name: “positive”}
];
```

> Expecting output like this below. It should be ordered based on band.

```
Var obj = [
{band: “4”, name: “positive”},
{band: “3”, name: “positive”}
{band: “-3”, name: “positive”},
{band: “2”, name: “positive”},
{band: “-2”, name: “positive”},
{band: “1”, name: “positive”}
];
```

Comment: Did you try to solve this? Add your code so we can help. Also, [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335497/can-i-completely-stop-using-var) not to use `var` any more.

Comment: Did you copy&paste this homework from Word or where do these strange "quotes" come from?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

In the `sort` callback, get the absolute value of the object's `band` property:

```js
const obj=[{band:"3",name:"positive"},{band:"-3",name:"positive"},{band:"1",name:"positive"},{band:"4",name:"positive"},{band:"-2",name:"positive"},{band:"2",name:"positive"}];

const result = obj.sort((a,b) => Math.abs(b.band) - Math.abs(a.band))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Is your `abs()` construct worth a new answer? -> [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)

Comment: And why `abs()` at all?

Comment: OP may want deterministic sorting of A and negative A.