# How to make a function add value to a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables

I am trying to make a button add an amount of points to another variable and then displaying the value of the variable as a score, but I cant seem to get it working.

I tried doing the following script but whenever I try to test it, the whole score variable disappears and i don't know what to do

```
<button onclick="addPoints25()">done</button>
<p id="counter"></p>

<script>

var points = 0;
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = points;

function addPoints25() {
    
    var points + 25;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have to update the element each time you update `points`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the textContent of the element when calling the function:

```js
const counter = document.getElementById("counter");
let points = 0;

counter.textContent = points;

function addPoints25() {
  points += 25;
  counter.textContent = points;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addPoints25()">done</button>
<p id="counter"></p>
```

* Note the [use of const and let instead of var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335497/can-i-completely-stop-using-var) and [textContent instead of innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427621/innertext-vs-innerhtml-vs-label-vs-text-vs-textcontent-vs-outertext)

**UPDATE**

The asker wants to store the points. This can be done different ways. One of them is via [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```js
const counter = document.getElementById("counter");
let points = Number(localStorage.getItem('points'));

counter.textContent = points;

function addPoints25() {
  points += 25;
  localStorage.setItem('points', points)
  counter.textContent = points;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addPoints25()">done</button>
<p id="counter"></p>
```

Comment: this worked really well, is there a way so when i refresh it doesn't reset back to 0?

Comment: yes. for example, you can use localstorage. i updated the answer

Comment: @MohamedSafwat u can upvote it and mark it as the accepted answer if was useful (:

Comment: one last tip - don't inline js functions in html - do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10607992/14569750) instead

Comment: yeah i did, I just posted it this way to show it better

Answer (score 1):

You have to just get the element of your counter once.

**Edited:** so that the code works with localstorage

Check [Addition_assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment) for more details of how to concatenate/sum values

```js
    //uncomment the next line to clear the localStorage
    //window.localStorage.clear();
    const counter = document.getElementById("counter");//get element
    let points = Number(localStorage.getItem(0));//declare var
    counter.textContent=points;//initial value set

    function addPoints25() {
        points += 25;//sum value
        window.localStorage.setItem(0, points);//update value in index 0 for the value of points variable
        //console.log(points);//for debugging purposes
        counter.textContent=localStorage[0];//update value in element
    }
```

Comment: this worked really well, is there a way so when i refresh it doesn't reset back to 0?

Comment: yes you can either store the value in a DB or use a localstorage

Comment: @MohamedSafwat I will update my answer, please check out and accept if this helped you

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to increase or add a fixed amount of number on each button click then you can try this:-

```
<button onclick="addPoints25()">done</button>
<p id="counter"></p>

<script>
let points = 0;
let scoreBoard = document.getElementById("counter")
scoreBoard.textContent = 0
function addPoints25(){
   points += 25;
   scoreBoard.textContent = points;
}
</script>
```

Comment: this worked really well, is there a way so when i refresh it doesn't reset back to 0?

Comment: You have to use localStorage for that