# Why I get Indefined when displaying Img’s on page?

Tags: javascript

I have been playing with this code for a while and I was wondering why when I try to add img’s to the array on the js code makes the images appear on DOM but also makes a bunch of Undefined elements appear, How can I just make the 15 images appear without the undefined? Thanks

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/josemon322/pen/OJoyYgK)

```js
var previous = document.getElementById('btnPrevious')
var next = document.getElementById('btnNext')
var gallery = document.getElementById('image-gallery')
var pageIndicator = document.getElementById('page')
var galleryDots = document.getElementById('gallery-dots');

var images = ["https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/internal_resources/1763/",
"https://cdn.britannica.com/56/234056-050-0AC049D7/first-image-from-James-Webb-Space-Telescope-deepest-and-sharpest-infrared-image-of-distant-universe-to-date-SMACS-0723.jpg",
"https://assets.newatlas.com/dims4/default/ac389ce/2147483647/strip/true/crop/1620x1080+150+0/resize/1200x800!/quality/90/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnewatlas-brightspot.s3.amazonaws.com%2Farchive%2Funiverse-expanding-acceleration-1.jpg",
"https://media.newyorker.com/photos/590966ee1c7a8e33fb38d6cc/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/Nissan-Universe-Shouts.jpg",
"https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/NY5k_3slMRttvtS7mA0SXm2WW9Q=/1500x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/smallerAndromeda-56a8ccf15f9b58b7d0f544fa.jpg",
"https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/05B8482C-0C04-4E41-859DCCED721883D2_source.jpg?w=590&h=800&7ADE2895-F6E3-4DF4-A11F51B652E9FA88",
"https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-thumb-66277237-200-huqebnzwetdsnnwvysbxemlskpcxnygf.jpeg",
"http://www.pioneertv.com/media/1090/hero_shot_1080x720.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=600&height=400&rnd=133159257140000000",
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRSWFW1EpMNFM5-dbZEUUnzJkzT3KbUCeuhPHx_eseFCpPeX4Q_DIVPopjS0LeKVmKdQho&usqp=CAU",
"https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/rwow8CCG3C3GrqHGiK8qcJ.jpg",
"https://static.wixstatic.com/media/917d103965314e2eacefed92edb6492c.jpg/v1/fill/w_640,h_356,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/917d103965314e2eacefed92edb6492c.jpg",
"https://astronomy.com/~/media/A5B9B6CF36484AB9A6FFAE136C55B355.jpg",
"https://discovery.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/discovery/fullset/2022/9/alien%20planet%20GettyImages-913058614.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.616.411.suffix/1664497398007.jpeg",
"https://images.newscientist.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/21180000/planet-10-orange-blue-final-small.jpg?crop=16:9,smart&width=1200&height=675&upscale=true",
"https://images.hindustantimes.com/img/2022/07/20/1600x900/Viral_Instagram_Planet_Rainbow_Nasa_1658316556293_1658316573815_1658316573815.PNG"


]
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  images.push({
    title: "Image " + (i + 1),
    source: images[i]
  });
}

var perPage = 8;
var page = 1;
var pages = Math.ceil(images.length / perPage)


// Gallery dots
for (var i = 0; i < pages; i++){
  var dot = document.createElement('button')
  var dotSpan = document.createElement('span')
  var dotNumber = document.createTextNode(i + 1)
  dot.classList.add('gallery-dot');
  dot.setAttribute('data-index', i);
  dotSpan.classList.add('sr-only');
  
  dotSpan.appendChild(dotNumber);
  dot.appendChild(dotSpan)
  
  dot.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var self = e.target
    goToPage(self.getAttribute('data-index'))
  })
  
  galleryDots.appendChild(dot)
}

// Previous Button
previous.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (page === 1) {
    page = 1;
  } else {
    page--;
    showImages();
  }
})

// Next Button
next.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (page < pages) {
    page++;
    showImages();
  }
})

// Jump to page
function goToPage(index) {
  index = parseInt(index);
  page =  index + 1;
  
  showImages();
}

// Load images
function showImages() {
  while(gallery.firstChild) gallery.removeChild(gallery.firstChild)
  
  var offset = (page - 1) * perPage;
  var dots = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-dot');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++){
    dots[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  
  dots[page - 1].classList.add('active');
  
  for (var i = offset; i < offset + perPage; i++) {
    if ( images[i] ) {
      var template = document.createElement('div');
      var title = document.createElement('p');
      var titleText = document.createTextNode(images[i].title);
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      
      template.classList.add('template')
      img.setAttribute("src", images[i].source);
      img.setAttribute('alt', images[i].title);

      title.appendChild(titleText);
      template.appendChild(img);
      template.appendChild(title);
      gallery.appendChild(template);      
    }
  }
  
  // Animate images
  var galleryItems = document.querySelectorAll('.template')
  for (var i = 0; i < galleryItems.length; i++) {
    var onAnimateItemIn = animateItemIn(i);
    setTimeout(onAnimateItemIn, i * 100);
  }
  
  function animateItemIn(i) {
    var item = galleryItems[i];
    return function() {
      item.classList.add('animate');
    }
  }
  
  // Update page indicator
  pageIndicator.textContent = "Page " + page + " of " + pages;
  
}

showImages();
```

Answer (score 2):

I checked your code and make it work with a small modification.
You are reusing the same array with the links of images and push inside the new object with the shape of `{ title, source }`.

You just need to do this changes:

1. Change the name of your array of images. Something from `images` to `arrayOfImages`.

```js
const arrayOfImages = ["https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/internal_resources/1763/", ...]
```

2. Declare an empty array before your first `for` loop. Make something like `const images = []`
3. On your `for` loop, instead of loop over the `images` variable, do it over the `arrayOfImages` variable.

```js
const images = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  images.push({
    title: "Image " + (i + 1),
    source: arrayOfImages[i]
  });
}
```

With those changes, everything works for me.

Also, as a recommendation, try to avoid the `var` keyword. If you want more details about this, this answer is very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50335579/17101307

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#map` to create a new array of objects from the array of URLS, then replace the original array.

```js
images = images.map((x, i) => ({
  title: "Image " + (i + 1),
  source: x
}));
```

Comment: See the code working on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0eaod4hq/).