# JS access existing variable through string

Tags: javascript, dynamic, variable-assignment

I am searching through existing data in Js through a variable, I found that maybe I can access the data through `window["variable_name"]` , but Js can't find the variable.

How am I going to access the data, or is there a better way to store the data and access it.

The data format

```
let info1=[{"id":0, "label":"XXX"},{"id":1, "label":"XXX"}, ...];
let info2=[{"id":0, "label":"XXX"},{"id":1, "label":"XXX"}, ...];
.
.
.
let info2000=[{"id":0, "label":"XXX"},{"id":1, "label":"XXX"}, ...];
```

Trying to access the variable

```
for (let i=1; i<=2000; i++) {
    console.log(window["info"+i]);
}
```

Comment: Are the variables being sought in global scope? Can you change their declaration to use `var` instead of `let`? In short, what constraints does a solution need to meet? I answered a similar question 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50111572/5217142) but is has limitations: - using `eval`  is never attractive and may be disabled in some run time environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant access the variable with window because you declared the variable with `let`. You need to use `var` to declare.

> Variables declared by let are only available inside the block where they're defined. Variables declared by var are available throughout the function in which they're declared.

```js
var info1=[{"id":0, "label":"XXX"},{"id":1, "label":"XXX"}];
var info2=[{"id":0, "label":"XXX"},{"id":1, "label":"XXX"}];

console.log(window["info1"]);
console.log(window["info2"]);
```