# How can i know if my class has a property

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello friends please how can i know if the className name contains a property 
since i'm using **Ajax** and i receive my class name as **data.className**

This is my code :

```
$.post(action, object, function(data){

    if(data.className.prototype.hasOwnProperty(data.methodName))
        console.log("the property exists")

    return data;
}, 'json');
```

My object :

```
{"className":"Quote", "methodName":"deleteQuote"}
```

This is my class Quote

```
class Quote{

    deleteQuote(callback){
        console.log("hello world");
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Here is a possible solution that does not involve eval. You would put the classes into a map, and use the map to refer to the objects by name.  https://yaoganglian.com/2013/07/17/javascript-class-from-string/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is in this part: `data.className.prototype`. Since `data.className == "Quote"`, this is equivalent to `"Quote".prototype`, which will get the prototype of the `String` class and not of the `Quote` class. So you want to convert the string `"Quote"` to the class which happens to be named `Quote`. Accessing variables named by a string is possible in Javascript as can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1366135/2804555). Unfortunately, this does not work for classes and the only fix seems to be using `eval`. The resulting code would look like this:

```js
var proto = eval(data.className+".prototype");
if(proto.hasOwnProperty(data.methodName))
    console.log("the property exists")
```

You should be careful when using `eval` because it might cause security issues. `eval` executes any code that is in the string that is passed as an argument. If you know for sure that `data.className` is a valid identifier, then this is not an issue. If you do not, you should first check that `data.className` is a valid JavaScript identifier. For how to do this, you can look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008279/validate-a-javascript-function-name).

Comment: TypeError: window[data.className] is undefined

Comment: @AmineBouhaddi Yes, unfortunately the solution I proposed did not actually work. I edited my answer to reflect that and added some code that should work

Comment: Firstly i thank you so much for your effort and help, and i want just to know if eval is secure ?

Comment: It is mostly not: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94017/what-are-the-security-issues-with-eval-in-javascript

Comment: @AmineBouhaddi I explained the security problems of using eval further

Comment: @MaxMeijer thank you can you help me more to check my identifier

Comment: @MaxMeijer i thank you so much, i have just one more question please 
how can i call the methodName if its exists

Comment: @AmineBouhaddi I recommend that you ask the security thing in a new question if you need more help with that. You have the code `var proto = eval(data.className+".prototype");` and want to check that `data.className` is a valid javascript identifier to avoid XSS

Comment: @AmineBouhaddi You can use `proto[data.methodName]()`

Comment: @MaxMeijer i thank you so much, i will create  a new function about the security

Comment: @MaxMeijer how can i create the object also please :)

Comment: @MaxMeijer  can you check my question her please ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56370348/how-can-i-call-a-function-inside-another-one-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment99343159_56370348